# Is there a way to output certain rows (or filter) from a table?

Tags: templating, table-field

Here's an example, I have three columns in a table: ClassQuarter, Course No, Description.

I would like to output rows only with ClassQuarter == '1' in a HTML table, then output rows where ClassQuarter == '2' in another table, then output rows where ClassQuarter == '3' in another table.

Am I able to output rows with a condition for the first column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there are a set number of quarters you can probably just collect the entries in a temporary array. Then use those to build your tables.

```
{% set quarter1 = [] %}
{% set quarter2 = [] %}
{% set quarter3 = [] %}

{% for row in entry.courses %}

    {% if row.classQuarter == 1 %}
        {% set quarter1 = quarter1|merge([row]) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if row.classQuarter == 2 %}
        {% set quarter2 = quarter2|merge([row]) %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if row.classQuarter == 3 %}
        {% set quarter3 = quarter3|merge([row]) %}
    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}

<table>
    {% for row in quarter1 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.courseNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.courseDescription }}</td>
        </tr>    
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<table>
    {% for row in quarter2 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.courseNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.courseDescription }}</td>
        </tr>    
    {% endfor %}
</table>

<table>
    {% for row in quarter3 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.courseNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.courseDescription }}</td>
        </tr>    
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

You could also add an 'if' clause in the 'for...in' loop. See the twig docs on [adding a condition](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#adding-a-condition) for more info.

```
<table>
    {% for row in entry.courses if row.classQuarter == 1 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.courseNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.courseDescription }}</td>
        </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<table>
    {% for row in entry.courses if row.classQuarter == 2 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.courseNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.courseDescription }}</td>
        </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
</table>
<table>
    {% for row in entry.courses if row.classQuarter == 3 %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ row.courseNumber }}</td>
            <td>{{ row.courseDescription }}</td>
        </tr> 
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

And could also probably condense that using the [range](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/range.html) shortcut.

```
{% for quarter in 1..4 %}
    <table>
        {% for row in entry.courses if row.classQuarter == quarter %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ row.courseNumber }}</td>
                <td>{{ row.courseDescription }}</td>
            </tr> 
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```